DataStage Client Method '~' of object '~' failed error

I have a problem with my ibm data stage client version 11.7 like the picture below when i start it.
I'm trying to uninstall and re-install several times but it wont help. How to fix it or how can i develop my new job ?
[![ds][1]][1]
